# Heroku Postgres with Spring boot JPA not working

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, heroku

I'm learning how to deploy on my heroku free account a spring boot application. Everything goes fine until I want to use a real Postgres database provides as one of the possible add-ons of Heroku.
I add my add-on and I'm able to get all the settings to connect to DB but when I create the JpaRepositories and the Pojos to be mapped to db, it's not able to create the database.

My Heroku dashboard gives me all the credentials to access to DB, and I use them in my spring boot application even if Heroku will change them periodically overriding them using environment variables.

Here the application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgres://xxxxxxxx:xxxxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxx
```

Even if I've read that Heroku will override datasource data using environment variable.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices</groupId>
<artifactId>DemoHeroku</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>DemoHeroku</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <version>1.16.10</version> <!-- added -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
package com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.DemoHeroku;

import com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.DemoHeroku.daos.AuthorDao;
import com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.DemoHeroku.daos.BookDao;
import com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.DemoHeroku.entities.Author;
import com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.DemoHeroku.entities.Book;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoHerokuApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoHerokuApplication.class, args);
}

@Autowired AuthorDao authorDao;
@Autowired BookDao bookDao;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String hello(){
    return "Hello!";
}

@RequestMapping("/books")
public List<Book> getBooks(){
    return bookDao.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping("/books/{id}")
public Book getOneBook(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id){
    return bookDao.findOne(id);
}

@RequestMapping("/authors")
public List<Author> getAuthors(){
    return authorDao.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping("/authors/{id}")
public Author getOneAuthor(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id){
    return authorDao.findOne(id);
}

@RequestMapping("/books/save")
public Book saveBook(@Valid Book book){
    return bookDao.save(book);
}

@RequestMapping("/books/delete/{id}")
public List<Book> deleteBook(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id){
    bookDao.delete(id);
    return bookDao.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping("/authors/save")
public Author saveAuthor(@Valid Author author){
    return authorDao.save(author);
}

@RequestMapping("/authors/delete/{id}")
public List<Author> deleteAuthor(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id){
    authorDao.delete(id);
    return authorDao.findAll();
}

@PostConstruct
private void fillDatabase(){
    authorDao.save(new Author(null, "Gino Camarda", "gino@quicktutorialz.com"));
    authorDao.save(new Author(null, "Attilia Nomeldini", "attilia@quicktutorialz.com"));

    bookDao.save(new Book(null, "Il basket per me", "Saggio sportivo", null, 1));
    bookDao.save(new Book(null, "W il basket", "Saggio sportivo", null, 1));

    bookDao.save(new Book(null, "Giornali e pareri", "Saggio giornalistico", null, 2));
    bookDao.save(new Book(null, "Versioni della verita", "Saggio giornalistico", null, 2));

}
}
```

Here my first POJOs:

```
package com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.DemoHeroku.entities;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity @Table(name="authors") @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor 
@Getter @Setter
public class Author {

  @Id @Column(name="ID") @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  @Column(name="NAME") @NotBlank
  private String name;
  @Column(name="EMAIL") @NotBlank
  private String email;
}
```

Here my second POJO:

```
package com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.DemoHeroku.entities;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity @Table(name="books")
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @Getter @Setter
public class Book {
  @Id @Column(name="ID") @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  @Column(name="TITLE") @NotBlank
  private String title;
  @Column(name="TITLE") @NotBlank
  private String description;
  @Column(name="TITLE")
  private Date dateOfRelease;
  @Column(name="TITLE") @NotNull
  private int authorId;

  @PrePersist
  private void setDate(){
    this.dateOfRelease = new Date();
  }
}
```

And these are the JpaRepositories.

AuthorDao.java:

```
package com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.DemoHeroku.daos;

import com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.DemoHeroku.entities.Author;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface AuthorDao extends JpaRepository<Author, Integer>{

}
```

BookDao.java

```
package com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.DemoHeroku.daos;

import com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.DemoHeroku.entities.Book;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BookDao extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer>{
}
```

When I try to package it with Maven locally, I get this error:

```
Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
```

When I deploy on Heroku my app crashes with general error:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
```

Comment: ok I remove it immediately

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to a copy past for the annotation @Column in Book pojo. There were columns with the exact same name!